# TextField, TextView Keyboard not disappearing when performing a segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I click on the textfield and the keyboard appears:

[image: image here]

When I click on the categories page it segues me to the next view controller like this:

[image: text field still shows up like this]

I already tried multiple ways of trying to remove the software keyboard such as this:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == descriptionField {
        self.view.endEditing(_:)
        descriptionField.resignFirstResponder()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToCategories", sender: self)
    } else if textField == setLocationField {
        self.view.endEditing(_:)
        setLocationField.resignFirstResponder()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSelectLocation", sender: self)
    }
}
```

but `self.view.endEditing` is not dismissing the keyboard. I also tried the `resignFirstResponder` for the textfields that could cause the issue but the keyboard is still not dismissing. I'm not sure if this is a bug or what.

Comment: Why are you trying to dismiss the keyboard and perform a segue inside the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method? That is called when a user taps in a text field.

Comment: because i'm trying to return a value from the location view. Is there anyway to still do this on a textfield or just simply use a button?

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate method textFieldShouldBeginEditing and inside that check if textField == descriptionField then return false.

Answer (score 0):

Resigning the first responder in `UITextFieldDelegate`'s textFieldShouldReturn(_:) method should be sufficient.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { 
    resignFirstResponder()
    return true 
}
```

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { 
  resignFirstResponder() 
   return true 
}

Or, a second option for multiple textfields inside of a view would be this solution:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: I already did both and it didn't work. What's interesting though is if you look at the keyboard on my screenshot it stacks the keyboard meaning there's 2 keyboard there.

Comment: @Jov if the textfield's text is being updated based on a selection (not manual text input), you could always cover it with an clear UIButton that handles showing a segue. Then have a delegate to update the text when it appears again.

Comment: yep thats what I had to do lol had to change alot of things but in the end that's the only thing that worked.

Comment: @Jov It's not always a bad thing! Separation of responsibilities is always the best practice. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Thanks @Sohail can you help me out with my other question about searching google maps?

Comment: @Jov I've never worked with that before but if you create a question I could check it out.